# Should I store state locally if I am using redux for state management?

Tags: javascript, redux

Coming from Elm background, there is no concept of local component state. And Redux is very similar to Elm Architecture.

When I use JavaScript Frameworks like React and Vue, each component has a local state. When I use Redux with these frameworks, **is it wise to put some state locally?** Or, should I stick to Elm like architecture for state management with Redux?

*Note: I am using Redux but not React.*

Comment: every component has its own local state and redux used to store the global state of the app as a whole

Answer (score 1):

When you use React, its best to stick with the concepts of React. According to React the visible component structure is represented by state and props. The fastest and easiest to manage the react UI is using the states which can be rerendered using `setState` function where as if you want to rerender using Reduct, you will have to `connect, dispatch and use props to rerender`, so its one step Vs 3 step process.

In react, the redux is used mainly for two functionalities,

- as a temporary and fast access storage area,
- way for multiple independent components to interact.

Comment: Not sure I completely agree. Even when you use React there are use cases for using Redux in combination with compinent’s local state.

Comment: Ofcourse, these are not mutually exclusive regarding a component. State is some data specific to that particular component but if a parent have to send some data to its child it will be send as props.

Comment: @user3210641 This is as per the OP's doubt that whether we should completely ignore using state and use redux props only for React app development.

Answer (score 0):

It is wise to store some state locally as there are numerious use cases for that.

Redux is used for managing application global state - you would for example store user’s session information or state shared across multiple components here.

Local state on the other state is used for - you guessed it - managing component’s local state (state which is independent on any other part of you app).

All though you could theorerically put everything into your Redux store it would be a nightmare to manage.